# How do I render a 'JSON get' request to a HTML page?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

How do I render a 'JSON get' request to a HTML page?

My code:

```javascript
var mId = 'MZWZMVZWJWY24';

var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.clover.com:443/v3/merchants/'+ mId +'/address',
    headers: {
        'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
        Authorization: 'Bearer efcbbf20-e31f-11db-892c-eddc691f7a33'
    }
};

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
    if (error) throw new Error(error);

    console.log(body);
});
```

I would like to send the results to page.html

Comment: please explain which _results_ you are talking about.

Comment: Could you clarify your question... Are you making this request from a node server or from the browser? What exactly are you trying to accomplish

Comment: @Maxwelll based on the looks it's Node.JS. He needs to probably link the HTML file and use handlebars to modify the page.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using Node.JS you also have to create a Web Server in order to render the JSON data you receive. You can do that using express and handlebars.

You'll use the server for rendering the HTML page while handlebars to display the data on the page.

If you are interested there are many tutorials on the internet about handlebars and Node.JS